# split single string element of array in different integer elements of array in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I have a input in below format and contain only numbers not alphabets:
arr = ['1 2 3 4 5 6']

I want to split all the numbers in below format:

arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

Comment: ```'1 2 3 4 5 6'.split(' ')```

Comment: could the array contain more than one string?

Comment: arr = ['1 2 3 4 5 6'];

console.log(arr[0].split(' '));

Comment: Could you please review and confirm/amend your example, please? Is the input an array of strings or a string? and, if it is an array, will it always contain only one item or it could contain more? Also, if the input is an array of strings what should be the output; a single array (`['1 2 3', '4 5 6']` becomes `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`) or a multi-dimensional array (`['1 2 3', '4 5 6']` becomes `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]`)?

Comment: If you think one of the answeres were helpful, mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like that:

```
const data = ['1 2 3 4 5 6'];

const newData = data
    .map(elem => elem.split(' ').map(elem => parseInt(elem)))
    .flat();
```

and if it's a multidimensional array like `['1 2 3 4 5 6', [ ['1 2 3 4 5 6'] ] ]`

you can just add `flat` function like that

```
const data = ['1 2 3 4 5 6', [['0 1 2']]];

const newData = data
    .flat(Infinity)
    .map(elem => {
    return elem.split(' ').map(elem => parseInt(elem));
  })
  .flat();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can do it like so

```js
arr[0].split(' ').map((n) => parseInt(n))
```

If array could contain multiple similar strings like so `['1 2 3 4', '5 6 7 8']`

```js
arr.map((string) => {
  string.split(' ').map((n) => parseInt(n))
}).flat();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Strings [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method to split at the whitespaces.

```js
let arr = ['1 2 3 4 5 6']
let res = arr[0].split(" ");

console.log(res);
```